# AngularJS ng-src does not update using $watch on $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

I am using the $rootScope to get and update an avatar. Now, when the user updates a new avatar, the **ng-src** of the  should also update, showing the new avatar that has just been uploaded.

I have realized this by watching the **$rootScope.myAvatar** in my controller and then setting the $scope.myAvatar to the newValue. Unfortunately, the ng-src is not updating in this case. I have read many questions concerning problems with ng-src and null values, but this is just a change in the $scope and I don't understand why updating $scope.myAvatar does not cause the change of ng-src. I have tried manually calling $scope.$apply(), it does not work as the $rootScope is still digesting.

router.js:

```
...
.when('/account', {
            'templateUrl': 'components/account/account.tpl.html',
            'controller': 'accountCtrl as ctrl',
            'auth': true,
            'reloadOnSearch': false
        })
...
```

Controller as ctrl:

```
function accountCtrl($scope, $rootScope, accountService) {
var vm = this;

accountService.getAvatar().then(function(res) {
    vm.myAvatar = res;
});

$rootScope.$watch('myAvatar', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
       vm.myAvatar = $rootScope.myAvatar;
    }
});

}
```

And the html:

```
<img ng-src="{{ctrl.myAvatar}}" alt="avatar" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Comment: `ctrl.myAvatar` isn't `$rootScope.myAvatar`, nor is it `$scope.myAvatar`.

Comment: sorry, look at the edited code. It's a variable vm which I use for the scope.

Comment: your value is property of object - use the object.property.

Comment: Is this a directive controller? Can you please post also the surrounding code? its hard to figure out with this few informations

Comment: added the surrounding ctrl and the service call on loading the ctrl. The ng-src should update when the avatar in the $rootScope is changed.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Can you please add the controller directive call in your template?! I think you missed the as-part like `ng-controller="AccountCtrl as ctrl"`

Comment: @micha149 I added the router.js.

Comment: I don't understand your use of the `$watch`, you can't watch `myAvatar` like that if it is attached to the functions `this`.

Comment: `ng-src` is watching the value change on the property. So when you do upload a new one it should reflect in the controller! What you should use is  an event aggregator or the built in event system.

Comment: Problem is that I use another controller (DialogCtrl) where the new avatar is uploaded. There I call something like $rootScope.updateAvatar() after finishing the upload. So I need a parent scope (i.e. rootScope) which both, the accountCtrl and the DialogCtrl have access to.

Comment: You're right, it does reflect it in the controller. I am logging it right after I set vm.myAvatar. Still, the image does not update.

Comment: Here is an example of inter controller communication: https://plnkr.co/edit/zr17Eyh0C2cjczSEIBfu?p=preview

Comment: And another example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/SZl8S2WNpj2kDWiZvmfs?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

I think your router configuration is wrong. Try the following one:

```
...
.when('/account', {
    'templateUrl': 'components/account/account.tpl.html',
    'controller': 'accountCtrl',
    'controllerAs': 'ctrl'
    'auth': true,
    'reloadOnSearch': false
})
...
```

Comment: yes it's correct. Works perfectly for everything else. This controller and the router config work for tens of lines of code.